# Trying to compute the sound pressure level in dB of a signal

Tags: microcontroller, analog

I'm trying to develop what's shown in the image below.

[image]

I already have everything developed and tested till the last amplifier that connects to the ADC, I see no point in it.
The signal that leaves the peak detector/RMS is centered around 2.5 V and can go till 5 V before it clips because of the op amps used, with this in mind I see no use in the second amplifier.

I intended to compute the SPL (sound pressure level) of the input signal using the microcontroller IDE, I'm not sure what exactly do here now.

[image]

The image above shows the voltages that the microphone will output depending on the SPL. One thing that I was thinking was using the approximated Vrms that i got in my analog circuit and use the equation for Vrms/dBSPL curve to obtain the SPL since now I have Vrms, but then again that also doesn't make any sense because I used an pre amplifier and that modified the signal.

So I was reading this:

[image]

[image]

Perhaps I could use equation 2.49 but I have no idea Km exactly is (the sensitivity of microphone with the amplifier, how does the amplifier change the sensitivity?)

Comment: "with this in mind i see no use in the second amplifier."  Check your ADC data sheet.  Some ADCs need a lower impedance source, or a source that has a healthy capacitance to ground, in order to work accurately.  **You're probably fine** -- but if there's a section in the datasheet on how to get the most accuracy out of your ADC, you really want to read it.

Answer (score 0):

If you stick with anything between 1 and 2 V then you have an adequate clipping margin as decent SNR.

Sound pressure cannot be determined without a power Amp, speaker & efficiency spec dBA/W @ 1m @ 1kHz.

A 1 Watt power output into 8 Ohms with an efficient 12" speaker with a Wizzer-cone into a large reflex cabinet with no crossover at 1 meter to something like -90  dBA.

This is adequate to produce a sound into an electret mic with typical gain and SNR to achieve a unity loop gain for measuring frequency response generate from MCU and speaker with high SNR. (> 60 dB)

p.s. If you use any garden variety speaker system with an amplifier, it expects around line voltage of 1V RMS for input then you will need a few more watts of power out at 1m distance.

> If you want to measure far-field then you seal the back filter, then use a tiny aperture to amplify just like in an iPod or iPad which converts air pressure waves into a clearer signal.